# Unable to import python module in custom environment

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to import PyQt5 module in a custom python environment but it fails. 
I have tested it with the system python and works fine

```
juan@juansphd:~/blender-2.82a-linux64/2.82/python/bin$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5.QtCore
>>>
```

but when I run python3 of my custom environment, it fails to load it

```
juan@juansphd:~/blender-2.82a-linux64/2.82/python/bin$ ./python3.7m
Python 3.7.4 (default, Oct  8 2019, 15:23:02)
[GCC 6.3.1 20170216 (Red Hat 6.3.1-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
>>>
```

I have tried adding `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, where PyQt5 is installed, into the `sys.path` but doesnt work neither

```
>>> sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages")
>>> import PyQt5.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'
>>>
```

How should I import the module?

Comment: How did you install the library, also could you provide the commands you used if you installed via pip? Also does this environment know about the existance of the library?

Comment: I used `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`. Not sure the custom environment knows about the existance of the library, thaths why I tried to do the sys.path.append

Comment: Maybe try to uninstall `pyqt5`, and then install it via `pip3`, if that doesnt work try normal `pip`

Comment: do you have more than one python interpreter?

Comment: yes, there is more than one interpreter, the system interpreter, which works fine, and the blender interpreter, which is the one Im trying to get pyqt5 in

Comment: @Webifycant actually uninstall pyqt5. Some kubuntu packages depend on it...